# Where are TODO patterns managed in PhpStorm /JetBrains IDE's and could they be shared?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to know where PhpStorm (and probably other JetBrains IDE's) manages the  [TODO patterns](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/todo-example.html)?
Is there a specific config file that holds the configured regex expressions?

I'm asking, because I would like to share the patterns:

1. with myself (Desktop <-> Laptop)
2. with team members per project. Best possible result would be to include them in the VCS

Is this possible?

*I currently use PhpStorm 2018.3.4*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sharing TODOs isn't possible (in an easy way) in PhpStorm.
Here's a feature request to make this possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77590 - feel free to give it a vote or comment

Comment: Do you know the uneasy way to share it and might consider an edit? It's sad that it's not implemented yet, but I would still be interested in the storage location where those settings are stored (if this exists)

Comment: @jowey Look for `<component name="TodoConfiguration">` node in `options\editor.xml` file. On Windows and PhpStorm 2018.2 that would be `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.PhpStorm2018.2\config\options\editor.xml`. For other OS see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: @jowey sorry I didn't add the uneasy method. Thanks LazyOne for adding it

Comment: Thank you both. This at least gives me the possiblity to share it on my own devices.

Comment: Update for version 2020.1 - the [default path for the configuration changed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/tuning-the-ide.html?_ga=2.247261645.892714463.1583138217-1949627378.1557918242#default-dirs) to `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\<product><version>`